# How to clone and append chose dropedown box using jq?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replicate some of my fields with chosen dropdown-box to clone and append using jq. Everything is working fine. But it is not replicating chosen dropdown.

HTML -

```
<div class="form-group row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <table width="100%" cellspacing="15" class="order-table"> 
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th width="50%">Product</th>
     <th width="50%">Quantity</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr class="clone-class">
       <td>
         <select name="productId[]" class="form-control chosen-select chosen" style="width: 100%;" 
            data-placeholder="Select">
            @foreach($product as $p)
              <option value="{{$p->id}}">{{$p->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
         </select>
       </td>
       <td>
        <input name="quantity[]" type="number" class="form-control" required>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
       <a class="btn btn-primary add-more-btn float-sm-right">Add</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Js -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clone = $('.clone-class').clone(true);
    console.log(clone);
    $('.clone-class select').chosen();

    jQuery('.add-more-btn').click(function() {
        var parent = jQuery('.clone-class').last();
         clone.clone(true).insertAfter(parent); 
         $('.clone-class:last select').chosen();
    }); 
});
```

On click of add button it is replicating expected fields but not dropdown as expected.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: What happens when you try `clone()` and `append()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be causing by `chosen-select chosen` class.

I have tried your code on `codepen`. Just remove those classes from `<select>` and add `data-live-search="true"`.

So your code will be -

```
<div class="form-group row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <table width="100%" cellspacing="15" class="order-table"> 
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th width="50%">Product</th>
     <th width="50%">Quantity</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr class="clone-class">
       <td>
         <select name="productId[]" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" 
            data-placeholder="Select" data-live-search="true">
            @foreach($product as $p)
              <option value="{{$p->id}}">{{$p->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
         </select>
       </td>
       <td>
        <input name="quantity[]" type="number" class="form-control" required>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
       <a class="btn btn-primary add-more-btn float-sm-right">Add</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And same js code.
Also, check working [codepen](https://codepen.io/abhishekhonrao/pen/JjXpGyM).